# passing array from ajax to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to pass an array variable from ajax to controller, 
but I am not getting the values in controller

below is my code

**AJAX**

```
 function userDetailsClass() {
          var userDetails = {};
          userDetails.age = 12;
          userDetails.Name = "Vignesh";
          userDetails.lastName = "s";
          debugger;

          $.ajax({
              url: "Home/userDetails",
              data: JSON.stringify({
                  UserDetailsParam: userDetails
              }),
              responseType: "json",
              success: successfn,
              error: errorfn
          });
          function successfn(result) {

          };

          function errorfn(result) {

          };
      }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult userDetails( string UserDetailsParam){
            return View();
        }
```

I also tried

```
public ActionResult userDetails( string[] UserDetailsParam){
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: I think you use the JSON.stringify the wrong way, you can find the [detail spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) from here, and when you want to transfer object to JSON, you just put the object in the method, as your example, JSON.stringify(userDetails) will return the JSON you want.

Comment: Sorry @winterfall I am a newbie to MVC and i am aware of how to pass models from ajax to controller

Comment: In my thinking, you want to send a JSON-format string to your server side, you named it with UserDetailsParam, and the real data is in the userDetails javascript object, JSON.stringify give you a method to transfer the javascript object to JSON-format string, so I think your code can change like this: `UserDetailsParam: JSON.stringify(userDetails)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this

```
     $.ajax({
          url: "Home/userDetails",
          data: {
              "UserDetailsParam":JSON.stringify(userDetails)//change this
          },
          responseType: "json",
          success: successfn,
          error: errorfn
      });
```

Comment: Thanks ! :)
In the controller I am not able to get an array if i deserialize the paramaeter passed!

Comment: i am also serializing parameters for sending like the way you are doing and by deserializing i was not able to get parameter as an array.

Comment: are you using the same code like this
var array = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(UserDetailsParam);

Comment: i am using this  Newtonsoft.Json dll for serializing and deserializing

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
var userDetails = {"age":'12',"Name":'Vignesh',"lastName":'s'};
```